# How to use swagger-autogen with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, swagger, auto-generate

I was wondering if it's possible to use swagger-autogen module in a Typescript project.
I have try many diffents ways but nothing to do. It always just says "Failed".
In a swagger.js file :

```
const swaggerAutogen = require("swagger-autogen")();
const options = {...}

const outputFile = './docs/swagger-output.json';
const endpointsFiles = ['./app.ts'];

swaggerAutogen(outputFile, endpointsFiles, options);
```

I've tried to put the file in the dist directory but same error...
Sorry if it's a stupid question or if I've just miss a key point.

Answer (score 3):

I tried wrapping the endpoint file with path.join and it successfully works! Just make sure we build first, then run the swagger.js file from the build/dist folder.

```ts
import path from 'path';
import swaggerAutogen from 'swagger-autogen';

const doc = {...} // update doc
const outputFile = './swagger-output.json';
const endpointsFiles = [path.join(__dirname, 'routes/routes.js')];
swaggerAutogen()(outputFile, endpointsFiles, doc);
```

Comment: Hi, you use 'routes/routes.js' but project contains `*.ts` files instead of '*.js'

Comment: Ok, I changed to `src/routes.ts` and it works

Comment: Can you share a test project, I'm stuck at this point, the generation is only showing `doc`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is try to specify your route file (such as router.ts or router/index.ts) in the `endpointsFiles` variable. And remember that swagger-autogen only does the static analysis of the files, that is, if your route properties are dynamically generated at runtime, swagger-autogen won't be able to interpret your code.

NOTE: Update to the latest version of the lib, because it contains some bug fixes about TypeScript.